# kali linux he can't use ALT+TAB to change between apps

Tags: kali-linux

A student has a problem with the following version of Kali:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="2024.1"
VERSION="2024.1"
VERSION_CODENAME=kali-rolling
ID=kali
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
```

When he opens a windows, he can´t maximize, and it appears occupying a quarter of the screen

Suddenly, he can't use ALT+TAB to change between apps.

[image: capture Kali]

why at any given time the windows cannot be resized and the ALT+TAB key combinations do not work?

Could it be from the graphics card or some resident process?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you have a question of some kind? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: [Kali questions tend to be poorly-received here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5257/86440), and in this particular instance I suspect you’ll get better support from the support URL given in the information you pasted in your question. Have you (or your student) tried [asking there](https://forums.kali.org/)?

Comment: In the forum https://forums.kali.org/, I cannot sign up. It is disabled for the forum administrator: Sorry, registration has been disabled by the administrator.

Comment: It looks like Kali is using Gnome desktop environment, and its window management process might have died, or perhaps failed to start at GUI login time. If a window manager dies, window decorations like window title bars vanish, and manipulating the windows becomes more difficult as only the bare X server window manipulation functions (unfamiliar to most people) will be available.

Comment: What windows manager do you advise me for Kali?